# How to get numbers of code line change in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm looking for a way in TFS, I need to **get the numbers of Code line change** for individual developer between 2 dates, do you think it is doable via TFS?

Any help is appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below SQL query statement:

```
   SELECT TeamProjectProjectNodeName 
          ,checkedinbyname 
          ,SUM([LinesAdded]) AS 
          ,SUM([LinesModified]) AS
          ,SUM([LinesAdded]+[LinesModified]) AS 
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MIN(DateTime),120) AS 
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX(DateTime),120) AS 
      FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[CodeChurnView] WHERE  TeamProjectProjectNodeName='xxx' AND  ChangesetTitle NOT LIKE 'xx'  AND FilenameFileExtension IN('.css','.cs','.aspx','.sql','js','.ascx') AND (LinesDeleted <>0 OR LinesModified<>0 OR FilenameFilePath LIKE '$/XX' AND FilenameFileExtension IN('.sql')) AND NetLinesAdded>=0   GROUP BY TeamProjectProjectNodeName, checkedinbyname 
    ORDER BY DESC
```

*Note: You must have permission to access the **Tfs_Warehouse** database to execute the above statement*.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the TFS data warehouse. There is a `FactCodeChurn` table that should contain the data you're after.